# Problem with second order optimality in KKT

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm solving an optimization problem with KKT method and I've found set of solutions for the problem that meat KKT conditions but now I'm trying to use **second order optimality condition** for my answer to see if it's a minimum or not but it seems that there is a problem which I can't figure it out.
the optimization problem is to **minimize**:

$ Minimize\space\space\space -5(x_{1} - 3)^2 + 12(x_{2} + 5)^2 - 6x_{1}x_{2} $

$ s.t.\space\space0 \leq x_{1} \leq 10 \space\space and\space\space 0 \leq x_{2} \leq 5$

by reformulation:

$ g_{1}(x):\space -x_{1} \leq 0 $

$ g_{2}(x):\space x_{1} - 10 \leq 0 $

$ g_{3}(x):\space -x_{2} \leq 0 $

$ g_{4}(x):\space x_{2} - 5 \leq 0 $

I solved and found the points meat KKT conditions that are:

$ P_{1} = (0, 0), \space\space\space\space P_{2} = (3, 0), \space\space P_{3} = (10, 0)$

But when I try to use **second order optimality condition** to determine if these points are minimum or not for example for $ P_{3} $ by:

$ \nabla g(x)d = 0 $

In which $\nabla g(x) $ is the matrix of active constraints gradients. here for $ P_{3} $ , $\space g_{2}(x) $ and $\space g_{3}(x) $ are active so:

$ \nabla g(x)d = 0 \to  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
d_{1} \\ d_{2}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}  \to d = \begin{pmatrix}
d_{1} \\ d_{2}
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} $

so when I try to determine the sign of

$ d^TH(x)d $

I end up with 0 that I don't know if it is minimum or maximum. so my problem is $ d = 0 $ and I can't figure out the sign of $ d^TH(x)d $ . How can I overcome this problem.